# Edited Entry Not Saving

Tags: php, mysql

I posted earlier about the Program Schedule Manager and the issue I was having with the time drowpdowns. Now I seem to be having an issue with the editing portion of the shows. When the the form is submitted it acts like it went through fine but the data isn't actually saved back to the database. Blow is the query I use for the saveBook() function.

Code from ./includes/ScheduleManager.class.php:

```
$query = "UPDATE PCR_Show_Schedule SET  `AirTime` = '".$AirTime."', `EndTime` = '".$EndTime."', `ShowName` = '".$ShowName."' , `ShowDesc` = '".$ShowDesc."' , `Sunday` = '".$Sunday."' , `Monday` = '".$Monday."' , `Tuesday` = '".$Tuesday."' , `Wednesday` = '".$Wednesday."' , `Thursday` = '".$Thursday."' , `Friday` = '".$Friday."' , `Saturday` = '".$Saturday."' WHERE `ID` = '".(int)$ID."'";
```

You can find the rest of the code here: https://github.com/phillf/ProgramScheduleManager

To be honest I am not totally sure what part of the code could be causing this issue.

Comment: If you are not totally sure what part causes an issue you should generally start isolating the part of the code that causes an issue.

Comment: I do have a feeling that it's the SQL query as I have never been able to wrap my head around them.

Comment: echo out the query string it is prob screwed up with quotes. just do an echo stmt fcs

Comment: Might be: ``ID` = '".(int)$ID."'"`  This implies that ID is numeric but you're wrapping it in ticks(')

Comment: Here is the echoed query string:

UPDATE PCR_Show_Schedule SET `AirTime` = '', `EndTime` = '', `ShowName` = '' , `ShowDesc` = '' , `Sunday` = '' , `Monday` = '' , `Tuesday` = '' , `Wednesday` = '' , `Thursday` = '' , `Friday` = '' , `Saturday` = '' WHERE `ID` = ''

Comment: based on this your .(int)$ID. variable isn't getting populated.   Are you UPDATing values or INSERTING values (should the statement be insert into table name or update?)

Comment: for that matter: none of the variables have values...

Comment: The statement should update the entry in the table.

Comment: Are you 100% sure `$ID` is the ID of an actually existing/exactly your entry? (Besides: Why do you put it into quotes, it _is_ a number since you cast it to `int`)